# Find single row from each group in GROUP BY clause in MySQL

Tags: mysql, group-by, subquery

I have a query with a subquery q1

```
SELECT skillset_name, level_name, level_value
FROM 
(SELECT ...) q1
WHERE met=1
```

It returns the following:

```
+------------------+------------+-------------+
| skillset_name    | level_name | level_value |
+------------------+------------+-------------+
| Python Fullstack | L1         |           1 |
| PHP Fullstack    | L2         |           2 |
| Java Fullstack   | L0         |           0 |
| Python Backend   | L1         |           1 |
| PHP Backend      | L2         |           2 |
| PHP Fullstack    | L1         |           1 |
| Python Fullstack | L2         |           2 |
| PHP Backend      | L1         |           1 |
| Python Backend   | L2         |           2 |
+------------------+------------+-------------+
```

Now I need to filter out it in such a way, that only the maximum level for each skillset name is returned, that is, I only need this:

```
+------------------+------------+-------------+
| skillset_name    | level_name | level_value |
+------------------+------------+-------------+
| PHP Fullstack    | L2         |           2 |
| Java Fullstack   | L0         |           0 |
| PHP Backend      | L2         |           2 |
| Python Fullstack | L2         |           2 |
| Python Backend   | L2         |           2 |
+------------------+------------+-------------+
```

How can I get that in MySQL (5.7)? I tried multiple ways using GROUP BY, but can't seem to get it working the right way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a join approach:

```sql
SELECT t1.skillset_name, t1.level_name, t1.level_value
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT skillset_name, MAX(level_value) AS max_level_value
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY skillset_name
) t2
    ON t2.skillset_name = t1.skillset_name AND
       t2.max_level_value = t1.level_value;
```

Comment: Do you mean the sub query is yourTable here? That query is a big one, and I would like to avoid duplicating it again if that's possible

Comment: This is one of the best ways to answer your question on MySQL 5.7.  I don't know what more I can say.

Comment: If there is no other way to do it without duplicating the subquery, then this would be my last resort. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you can group by skillset_name and level_name, then select max(level_value) should be ok

Comment: Hey, thanks; but it doesn't seem to be working. It returns all the rows. I tried this:

SELECT skillset_name, MAX(level_value)
FROM 
(SELECT ....) q1
WHERE met=1

GROUP BY skillset_name, level_name